# Can a DTD attribute be fixed AND required?

Tags: xml, dtd

Can a DTD attribute be fixed AND required?

```
<!ATTLIST myTag myAttribute CDATA #FIXED #REQUIRED "some text">
```

Answer (score 3):

Daniel Haley is correct, at least as regards the syntax of DTDs.

If you want all occurrences of an attribute to have a given value, *and* you want to require that value to be physically present in the XML document (not present by the default-value mechanism), *and* if the value is a legal NMTOKEN, then you can achieve the behavior you want by a different route:

```
<!ATTLIST myTag 
   myAttribute (some-text) #REQUIRED >
```

Here the attribute-type information `(some-text)` specifies that the only valid value for `myAttribute` is `some-text`, and the `#REQUIRED` keyword imposes the constraint that `myAttribute` must be physically present in the input.

If the value you want is not a legal NMTOKEN -- if it's an absolute URI, for instance, or a phrase with spaces or non-name-characters in it -- then this technique won't work.

Answer (score 2):

No, the attribute declaration cannot have both `#FIXED` and `#REQUIRED`.

If the attribute is `#FIXED`, the value is always what's specified in the declaration, even if the attribute is not physically in the XML.

For example, in the following XML the value of the `test` attribute is `bar` even though the attribute is not actually specified in the XML itself:

```
<!DOCTYPE foo [
<!ELEMENT foo EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST foo
          test CDATA #FIXED 'bar'>
]>
<foo/>
```

Here's proof via an XSLT transform:

**XSLT 2.0** (it's valid 1.0 too)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/foo">
        <results>
            <xsl:value-of select="@test"/>          
        </results>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<results>bar</results>
```